# Angular - How do you animate a list of components with stagger

Tags: angular, animation, angular-components, angular-animations

How do you animate a list of components with stagger?
I added also a working version without a list of components and this works.

As I said I want to use components in stead "rendering" the components in my page

ts-file:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { trigger, transition, style, animate, query, stagger } from '@angular/animations';

const listAnimation = trigger('listAnimation', [
  transition('* <=> *', [
    query(':enter',
      [style({ opacity: 0 }), stagger('60ms', animate('600ms ease-out', style({ opacity: 1 })))],
      { optional: true }
    ),
    query(':leave',
      animate('200ms', style({ opacity: 0 })),
      { optional: true}
    )
  ])
]);

@Component({
  selector: 'app-somelist',
  templateUrl: './some-list.component.html',
  animations: [listAnimation]
})

export class NocOverviewComponent {
  items = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21];
}
```

html (not working):

```
<div [@listAnimation]="items.length">
  <app-list-item *ngFor="let item of items; let i = index">some list item- {{i}}</app-list-item>
</div>
```

HTML (this works)

```
<div [@fadeInListAnimation]="items.length">
  <div class="item" *ngFor="let item of items; let i = index">
    some list item- {{i}}
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You can use also https://animate.style/ animated css. After imported its css just add class like class='animated fadeIn'

Comment: and I can't see any error in code https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qjcfcu

Comment: Thank you for your review. animate.css or just plain css(animations) wil not create the effect that I want. it will animate the components exact at the same time and not as a sequence.  In your example you use a span and not a component. as I mentioned in my question.

Answer (score 0):

I also struggled with a similar issue. After a couple hours of trying to use stagger my solution was to delay adding the components to the array with a setTimeout() instead of using the stagger animation.

So your example could look like:

```
const listAnimation = trigger('listAnimation', [
    transition(':enter', [
      style({ opacity: 0 }), 
      animate('600ms ease-out', style({ opacity: 1 }))
    ]),
    transition(':leave', [
      animate('200ms', style({ opacity: 0 }))
    ])
]);

<div *ngFor="let item of items" @listAnimation>
  {{ item }}
</div>

export class NocOverviewComponent {
  items: number[] = [];
  delay: number = 60; // Timing of the stagger in milliseconds

  constructor() {
    this.populateItems();
  }

  populateItems(): number[] {
    let count = 0;
    while (count < 22) {
      this.items.push(count);
      setTimeout(() => {
        ++count;
      }, this.delay);
  };
}
```

Comment: thank you for this update/soloution. This is also an option, but I do not want't to use a delay.